# 4 IF AND Statements in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

Trying to get two equations to then present one of four options.

Example:

[image]

Have no idea where to start, all four need to sit in the one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(O34 > O33; Q34 > Q33); Z28; 
 IF(AND(O34 < O33; Q34 > Q33); Z29;
 IF(AND(O34 > O33; Q34 < Q33); Z30;
 IF(AND(O34 < O33; Q34 > Q33); Z31; ))))
```

If you want to include equality add **`=`** behind **`><`** like: **`<=`** or **`>=`**. 
 For inequality use: **`<>`**. Also, **`AND`** can be changed to **`OR`** if you need such logic.